# How to politely ask “What do you really mean?”

Tags: translation, politeness, phrase-request, formal, informal

Every now and then in conversation it’s normal for us to have suspicions about the true intentions of a question, comment, proposal, etc., that someone says to us. Having some standard responses ready would be useful.

Of course they may not directly explain even then, so should the next response get less polite, or more?

Comment: The question is too broad, depending on the content of the conversation,  “What do you really mean?” can be interpreted in many different ways. It is better to narrow it down to a specific situation that you want to use this phrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to say it. The 6 pairs below arranged from polite with respect --> polite --> demanding w/patience --> demanding w/impatience.

1a - 我不太瞭解***您***的意思, 可以***請您***解釋解釋嗎?

1b - 我不太瞭解***您***所說的, 可以***請您***解釋一下嗎?

2a - 我不太瞭解***您***的意思, 可以***麻煩您***解釋解釋嗎?

2b - 我不太瞭解***您***所說的, 可以***麻煩您***解釋一下嗎?

3a - 我不瞭解***你***的意思, ***勞駕***解釋解釋好嗎?

3b - 我不瞭解***你***所說的, ***勞駕***解釋一下好嗎?

4a - 我不瞭解***你***的意思, 解釋解釋好吧?

4b - 我不瞭解***你***所說的, 解釋一下好吧?

5a - 我不瞭解***你***的意思, 解釋解釋吧!

5b - 我不瞭解***你***所說的, 解釋一下吧!

6a - 我聽不懂***你***的意思, 解釋解釋.

6b - 我聽不懂***你***所說的, 解釋清楚一點.

Comment: @dROOOze Thanks for correcting the word.

Comment: Note that in these sentences, "瞭解" and "懂" can be replaced with "明白".